# Running OS off RAIDed drive?

Tags: ssd, mac-pro, raid

I recently asked about [bottlenecks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215354/identifying-bottlenecks) in the Mac architecture (The Mac Pro 12 core 2010 model) to try to create a set up that optimizes performance.

It was my intention to take 2 SSDs and RAID them on a PCI card to get a faster OS drive speed. I read an article at the Apple discussion board [Considering RAID 0 or RAID 1?](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-6002) and was a bit alarmed to read this warning:

> Apple will not allow OS X to be installed on a RAID set, so forget
>   about going there to speed up your machine, get a SSD instead.

Before I go through the time and effort, can someone verify if this is right? I've been searching for an hour and seeing only discussions of how to RAID and the various options, but no other remarks on running OS not being viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only positive evidence I can find is one can install  [*Mac OS X server*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202307) on a software RAID set. The instructions state that a standard Mac OS X needs to be installed before the Server software installation. The only drawback is that, [among other things](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201316), a Recovery volume cannot be created and FileVault cannot be used.

One could interpolate that you can indeed install Mac OS X on a RAID, but some very important technologies will not be available.

Comment: Got it, that pretty much answers my question. I'll probably use the second SSD like I do in my current MacPro, to boot to a different OS.

Comment: Note: I haven't done this kind of RAID setup myself, so it will be worth a short regime of testing on your part to make sure it works as you expect it to before you put it into production. Once you determine that it is a solid setup, you might want to come back to your question and add some configuration details for future visitors in search of the same solution. Conversely, if you find it is truly impossible to set up this configuration, then it may be useful to set warning flags. Good luck!